# Bullet rotation unwanted offset Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to have an enemy circle the player and shoot bullets at said player. Whenever the enemy shoots though, the bullet is slightly off from the player and continues to shoot further from the players position.

this is the enemies behaviour

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CirclingScript : MonoBehaviour, IPooledObject
{

public Transform tf;
public Transform Target;

public GameObject Ship;
public GameObject WaveMaker;
public EnemyScript enemyscript;

public string BulletName;

ObjectPools objectPooler;

private int I; // Wave number
public int BulletAmount;

public float angle;
public float Radius;
public float RotateSpeed;
private float Timer;
public float Health;

private Quaternion BulletRot;

public void OnObjectSpawn()
{

    WaveMaker = GameObject.Find("EnemyWaveMaker");//gets the game object
    enemyscript = WaveMaker.GetComponent<EnemyScript>();// gets the scripts for the wave makers
    I = enemyscript.i;

    Ship = GameObject.Find("Ship");//gets the game object
    Target = Ship.GetComponent<Transform>();// gets the Transform 

    //https://answers.unity.com/questions/1068513/place-8-objects-around-a-target-gameobject.html thank you ^-^
    angle = enemyscript.RotSpace * Mathf.PI * 2f / enemyscript.Waves[I].Amount;

    RotateSpeed = enemyscript.Waves[I].RotateSpeed;
    Radius = enemyscript.Waves[I].Radius;

}

void Start()
{

    objectPooler = ObjectPools.Instance;

}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Bullet"))
    {
        Health -= coll.GetComponent<DamageScript>().Damage;

    }

    if (Health <= 0)
    {

        objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Boom", tf.position, Quaternion.identity);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);

    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    angle += RotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    Timer += Time.deltaTime;

    Vector2 offset = new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(angle), Mathf.Cos(angle)) * Radius;
    tf.position = (Vector2)Target.position + offset;

    if (Timer >= 2f)
    {
        Vector3 difference = Target.position - tf.position;
        float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        BulletPatternsModule.ShootArc(angle, BulletAmount, BulletName, tf, rotationZ);
        Timer = 0f;
    }
}
}
```

and the code for shooting the bullets

```
    public static void ShootArc(float ArcSize, int BulletAmount, string BulletName, Transform tf, float Offset)//All arcs are in angles, not radians
{
    float angle = 0;
    angle = Offset;//Offset is to the left
    for (int i = 0; i < BulletAmount; i++)
    {
        float AngleStep = ArcSize / BulletAmount;//Gets the step size for arc
        angle += AngleStep;
        objectPooler.SpawnFromPool(BulletName, tf.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle));//Shoots the bullet
    }
}
```

The offset makes the enemies near useless

Any help would be appreciated :)
(more text in order for me to post the question. Isn't this fun?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to make the enemy look at the player using this function

```
transform.LookAt(target.position);
```

Comment: It is the rotation of the bullet that is not correct. I can understand where you are coming from though

Comment: So your bullet is a physics body? Have you tried first setting the bullet velocity to Vector3(0, 0, 0);  and then giving it a forward force?

Comment: The bullet uses Translate for movement. It is the code for rotation that is the problem. The bullets work fine

Comment: Does the bullet come from somewhere that is not the center of the enemy? There is a quick and dirty solution for this. When the bullet is spawned, just rotate it towards the player.

Comment: I can set the position of the bullet. It uses a general bullet class so doing a quick rotate wouldn't be the best. the bullet also has to deal with being spawned in a potential arc.

Comment: In your calculation of the offset i see this code "angle += RotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;" this is the reason why every shot is further from the player. The angle keeps getting higher, and so does the offset. For the angle you could use angles from the transform of the player and enemy and calculate it from there.

Comment: I've managed to single out the enemies angle calculation as the main cause of the issue. Bullet spawning is fine.

Comment: just find a way to calculate the angle using the actualy positions of the player and enemy rather than adding a rotation speed, because that doesnt account for distance and player movement.

Comment: You can use Atan2 from Mathf like so "atan2(position1.y - position2.y, position1.x - position2.x);" and this will give you an angle between the two objects. It could possibly work as Angle

Comment: I have found and fixed the issue, I was using the float for circling the player in the arc size. This is what caused the accumulative error.